# What would "Politics Pipeline" be in this text?

Tags: meaning, headlinese

I came across this headline on NYTimes:

> American Idols: Dr. Oz, Trump and the Celebrity to Politics Pipeline

I think it is a podcast and a I'm not an experienced English listener.

But it kept me thinking about possible meanings of "Politics Pipeline" one reigning thought is that the author is talking about the building of a pipeline that is to field to political interest and it should not be, but they use the celebrity culture to involve people. Am I close enough?

Comment: I think it is probably a pipeline from celebrity to politics. It is a headline where the usual rules do not apply so it is hard to be 100% sure.

Comment: I agree, I think you are parsing it slightly wrong.  It isn't "politics pipeline" as one item, it's the *celebrity-to-politics pipeline*, which should have been written like that to make it clearer.

Comment: @all, that makes more sense than what I have thought. But please allow me to ask: could thta possibly mean hat I thought it was? "building of a pipeline that is to tield to political interest "? with that same writings?

Comment: As a British person I had to look up who 'Dr. Oz' is - it confirmed my suspicion that  the headline refers to celebrities who became politicians. The 'pipeline' is a metaphorical one.

Comment: @Kate Bunting, I did the same after what stargon and mdewey said. But now a wonder if the phrase "Politics Pipeline" could also mean about  "the building of a pipeline that is to tield to political interest"? I mean using the same phrase  "Politics Pipeline" to mean what I thought it was

Comment: As I said, it's a metaphorical 'pipeline' carrying people from celebrity to politics. I doubt very much that it refers to a real one. Anyway, can't you tell from reading the article?

Comment: "A pipeline that is tied to political interests" would probably be a *political pipeline*, not a *politics pipeline*.

Comment: @stangdon, that was very clarifying thanks. So the sentence "Dr. Oz, Trump and the Celebrity to POLITICAL Pipeline" could convey the meaning of celebrity (even former celebrity) influencing people in building of a pipeline (that is surreptitiously tied to political interest ) to get behind the ideia of the pipeline in case they weren't accepting it. Right?

Comment: @thonyalbuquerque Unfortunately, "Dr. Oz, Trump and the Celebrity to POLITICAL Pipeline" doesn't really make sense.  "The celebrity to political pipeline" is hard to interpret, because there's no verb in there.  It doesn't sound like "celebrities influencing a pipeline that is a political issue."  It sounds like Dr. Oz, Trump, and someone called "the celebrity" are going to do something called "political pipeline".  (To be continued...)

Comment: @thonyalbuquerque If we want to talk about celebrity influence, we'd probably say something like "Dr. Oz, Trump, and celebrity influence on a political (or *politicized*) pipeline" or maybe "Dr. Oz, Trump to influence political (again, or *politicized*) pipeline".  This is a very tricky question partly because this is about **headlinese**, which has its own strange set of rules.